# Is it possible to quickly and easily toggle VPN off and on at router level?

Tags: router, vpn, dd-wrt

Through DD-WRT or something similar, is it possible to toggle off and on a connection to a VPN? Would a script sat on a machine within the home network do the trick?

The intention is to get a non-country restricted VPN so that I can access US Netflix in the UK and such, through a smart Blu-Ray player (meaning that I can't just set the VPN up on a laptop - it has to be at router level). The ease of toggling is needed to revert the connection to its defaults for normal usage/UK Netflix, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, if you are willing to run a shell script on your router. The command

```
   nvram set opvpn_cfg='
   client
   remote xx.yy.ww.zz
   ....
   <ca> 
   ---------BEGIN CERTFICATE--------------
   ...
   --------END CERTIFICATE--------------
   </ca>
   <key>
   ....
   '
```

will create your config file, which you can start as follow:

```
   mkdir /tmp/openvpn
   cd /tmp/ovpn
   nvram get ovpn_cfg>ovpn.conf
   mkdir -p /tmp/etc/config
   echo -e "#!/bin/sh\nkillall openvpn\nping -c4 localhost\nopenvpn --daemon --config     /tmp/ovpn/ovpn.conf">/tmp/etc/config/ovpn.wanup
   chmod +x /tmp/etc/config/ovpn.wanup
   openvpn --daemon --config ovpn.conf
```

This command will stop the OpenVPN:

```
   killall openvpn
```

If you wish, you can put the above commands into a script file, and have it executed at boot:

```
   nvram set rc_startup='mkdir /tmp/ovpn
   cd /tmp/ovpn
   nvram get ovpn_cfg>ovpn.conf
   mkdir -p /tmp/etc/config
   echo -e "#!/bin/sh\nkillall openvpn\nping -c4 localhost\nopenvpn --daemon --config /tmp/ovpn/ovpn.conf">/tmp/etc/config/ovpn.wanup
   openvpn --daemon --config ovpn.conf'
```

These are rather generic, but you should be able to mold these as per your needs.